# Container runs locally but fails in ACI

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I created a sample asp.net core application generated by dotnet new web. Added a docker file exposing port 5000.

Docker file is below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Sampleapp.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Sampleapp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Sampleapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sampleapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sampleapp.dll"]
```

This works fine when I run it locally on my desktop. However, when I add it to ACR and run it in ACI it fails.

```
az container create --resource-group $res_grp `
                    --name $aci_container_name `
                    --image $image_name `
                    --registry-login-server $registry_login_server `
                    --registry-username $akv_pull_usernamevalue `
                    --registry-password $akv_pullpasswordvalue `
                    --dns-name-label $dns_name_label `
                    --output table

Name              ResourceGroup       Status    Image                                                 IP:ports          Network    CPU/Memory       OsType    Location
----------------  ------------------  --------  ----------------------------------------------------  ----------------  ---------  ---------------  --------  -------------
aci0734container  containerbasics_rg  Running   devcontainerregistry0734.azurecr.io/helloacrworld:v1  20.53.163.177:80  Public     1.0 core/1.5 gb  Linux     australiaeast
```

There are no error logs too.

```
az container logs --resource-group containerbasics_rg --name aci0734container

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

When I try to curl this is response

```
curl http://20.53.163.177:5000
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://20.53.163.177:5000
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I run it locally I map the destination port but ACI does not allow port mapping. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the non-standard port by adding `--ports 5000`. ACI is defaulting to port 80 and your instance is listening and exposing port 5000:

```
az container create --resource-group $res_grp `
                --name $aci_container_name `
                --image $image_name `
                --registry-login-server $registry_login_server `
                --registry-username $akv_pull_usernamevalue `
                --registry-password $akv_pullpasswordvalue `
                --dns-name-label $dns_name_label `
                --ports 5000 `
                --output table
```

Comment: That definitely works... i was under the impression that port mapping is not supported based on this https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/34082284-support-for-port-mapping but then did not realize you can still use the original port number.

Comment: Yes you are correct, port mapping is not supported. i.e. with ACI you are unable to map external port 80 on external IP -> 5000 on the container. As your Dockerfile specifies running as a non-privileged user you cannot run it by exposing port 80. So you will need to expose it on 5000 as above or run as a privileged user.